# Major errors in code after not running it for a year

Tags: flutter, dart, debugging, flutter-test, dart-null-safety

Hi I recently started working on a project that had been put aside for a long time, +- 1 year. I opened it up and some widgets like flatbutton were deprecated and I had to correct them to textbutton etc. But after all that I tried running the code but I am getting more errors in the debug colsole, some of them were to do with null safety so I turned it off but even so I am still getting a bunch of errors which I cannot find the fix to, and they are so many that it would take days to go through all of them and fix them individually, does anyone know what I could do to fix this? The project was working perfectly at the time it was put aside and no changes were made to it but it's just not working anymore now. Here is what the debug console is giving. Any solutions would be greatly appreciated.

```
 Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/dropdownfield-1.0.3/lib/dropdownfield.dart:119:25: Error: No named parameter with the name 'autovalidate'.
                        autovalidate: true,
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_form_field.dart:97:3: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  TextFormField({
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/dropdownfield-1.0.3/lib/dropdownfield.dart:88:11: Error: No named parameter with the name 'autovalidate'.
          autovalidate: false,
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider_windows-0.0.4+3/lib/src/path_provider_windows_real.dart:126:25: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
- 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
          knownFolderID.addressOf, KF_FLAG_DEFAULT, NULL, pathPtrPtr);
                        ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:1067:7: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'LOGFONT'.
- 'LOGFONT' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
      addressOf.cast<Uint8>().elementAt(28).cast<Utf16>();
      ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:1112:29: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'ENUMLOGFONTEX'.
- 'ENUMLOGFONTEX' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  LOGFONT get elfLogFont => addressOf.cast<LOGFONT>().ref;
                            ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:1114:29: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'ENUMLOGFONTEX'.

- 'ENUMLOGFONTEX' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  String get elfFullName => addressOf
                            ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:1120:26: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'ENUMLOGFONTEX'.
- 'ENUMLOGFONTEX' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  String get elfStyle => addressOf
                         ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:1126:27: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'ENUMLOGFONTEX'.
- 'ENUMLOGFONTEX' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  String get elfScript => addressOf
                          ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2688:7: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'OSVERSIONINFO'.
- 'OSVERSIONINFO' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
      addressOf.cast<Uint8>().elementAt(20).cast<Utf16>().unpackString(128);
      ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2699:11: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'OSVERSIONINFO'.
- 'OSVERSIONINFO' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
        ..addressOf.cast<Uint8>().elementAt(20).value = 0;
          ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2744:24: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO'.
- 'BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  String get szName => addressOf
                       ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2837:7: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO'.
- 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
      addressOf.cast<Uint8>().elementAt(BTH_MAX_PIN_SIZE).value;
      ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2840:5: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO'.
- 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
    addressOf.cast<Uint8>().elementAt(BTH_MAX_PIN_SIZE).value =
    ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2845:28: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO'.
- 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
      String.fromCharCodes(addressOf.cast<Uint8>().asTypedList(pinLength));
                           ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2853:7: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO'.
- 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
      addressOf.cast<Uint8>().elementAt(idx).value = pinData[idx];
      ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/com/combase.dart:38:31: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.

- 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  final iid = GUID.allocate().addressOf;
                              ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/com/combase.dart:56:33: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
- 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  final clsid = GUID.allocate().addressOf;
                                ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/utf8.dart:63:33: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'Utf8'.
- 'Utf8' is from 'package:ffi/src/utf8.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/utf8.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  String toString() => fromUtf8(addressOf);
                                ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IWbemLocator.dart:82:38: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'COMObject'.
- 'COMObject' is from 'package:win32/src/com/combase.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/com/combase.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
    final ptr = COMObject.allocate().addressOf;
                                     ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IWbemLocator.dart:84:68: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
- 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
    final hr = CoCreateInstance(GUID.fromString(CLSID_WbemLocator).addressOf,
                                                                   ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IWbemLocator.dart:85:64: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
- 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
        nullptr, CLSCTX_ALL, GUID.fromString(IID_IWbemLocator).addressOf, ptr);
                                                               ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/INetworkListManager.dart:128:38: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'COMObject'.
- 'COMObject' is from 'package:win32/src/com/combase.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/com/combase.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
    final ptr = COMObject.allocate().addressOf;
                                     ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/INetworkListManager.dart:131:51: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.

- 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
        GUID.fromString(CLSID_NetworkListManager).addressOf,
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/INetworkListManager.dart:134:50: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
- 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
        GUID.fromString(IID_INetworkListManager).addressOf,
                                                 ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IKnownFolderManager.dart:164:38: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'COMObject'.
- 'COMObject' is from 'package:win32/src/com/combase.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/com/combase.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
    final ptr = COMObject.allocate().addressOf;
                                     ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IKnownFolderManager.dart:167:51: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
- 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
        GUID.fromString(CLSID_KnownFolderManager).addressOf,
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IKnownFolderManager.dart:170:50: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
- 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
        GUID.fromString(IID_IKnownFolderManager).addressOf,
                                                 ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IFileSaveDialog.dart:99:38: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'COMObject'.
- 'COMObject' is from 'package:win32/src/com/combase.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/com/combase.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.

    final ptr = COMObject.allocate().addressOf;
                                     ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IFileSaveDialog.dart:102:47: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.

- 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.

        GUID.fromString(CLSID_FileSaveDialog).addressOf,
                                              ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IFileSaveDialog.dart:105:46: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
- 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
        GUID.fromString(IID_IFileSaveDialog).addressOf,
                                             ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IFileOpenDialog.dart:58:38: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'COMObject'.
- 'COMObject' is from 'package:win32/src/com/combase.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/com/combase.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
    final ptr = COMObject.allocate().addressOf;
                                     ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IFileOpenDialog.dart:61:47: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
- 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
        GUID.fromString(CLSID_FileOpenDialog).addressOf,
                                              ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IFileOpenDialog.dart:64:46: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
- 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
        GUID.fromString(IID_IFileOpenDialog).addressOf,
                                             ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IDesktopWallpaper.dart:197:38: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'COMObject'.
- 'COMObject' is from 'package:win32/src/com/combase.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/com/combase.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
    final ptr = COMObject.allocate().addressOf;
                                     ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IDesktopWallpaper.dart:200:49: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
- 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
        GUID.fromString(CLSID_DesktopWallpaper).addressOf,
                                                ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IDesktopWallpaper.dart:203:48: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
- 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.

        GUID.fromString(IID_IDesktopWallpaper).addressOf,
                                               ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/winrt/winrt_helpers.dart:86:40: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
- 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  final riidCalendar = GUID.allocate().addressOf;
                                       ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/platform-2.2.1/lib/src/interface/local_platform.dart:45:41: Error: Member not found: 'packageRoot'.
  String get packageRoot => io.Platform.packageRoot;
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/filesystem_picker-1.0.3/lib/src/picker_page.dart:187:63: Error: The getter 'title' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.
- 'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'title'.
                    color: AppBarTheme.of(context).textTheme?.title?.color ??
                                                              ^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/filesystem_picker-1.0.3/lib/src/picker_page.dart:188:61: Error: The getter 'title' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.
- 'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'title'.
                        Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme?.title?.color),
                                                            ^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/filesystem_picker-1.0.3/lib/src/picker_page.dart:234:26: Error: The getter 'FlatButton' isn't defined for the class '_FilesystemPickerState'.
- '_FilesystemPickerState' is from 'package:filesystem_picker/src/picker_page.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/filesystem_picker-1.0.3/lib/src/picker_page.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'FlatButton'.
                  child: FlatButton.icon(
                         ^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/filesystem_picker-1.0.3/lib/src/picker_page.dart:236:60: Error: The getter 'title' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.
- 'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'title'.
                        AppBarTheme.of(context).textTheme?.title?.color ??
                                                           ^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/filesystem_picker-1.0.3/lib/src/picker_page.dart:237:65: Error: The getter 'title' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.
- 'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'title'.
                            Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme?.title?.color,
                                                                ^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/filesystem_picker-1.0.3/lib/src/picker_page.dart:240:35: Error: The getter 'title' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.
- 'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'title'.
                                ?.title
                                  ^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/filesystem_picker-1.0.3/lib/src/picker_page.dart:242:65: Error: The getter 'title' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.
- 'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'title'.
                            Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme?.title?.color)
                                                                ^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/filesystem_picker-1.0.3/lib/src/breadcrumbs.dart:65:22: Error: The method 'FlatButton' isn't defined for the class 'Breadcrumbs<T>'.
- 'Breadcrumbs' is from 'package:filesystem_picker/src/breadcrumbs.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/filesystem_picker-1.0.3/lib/src/breadcrumbs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'FlatButton'.
              child: FlatButton(
                     ^^^^^^^^^^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1159

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 29s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Comment: Flutter version is upgraded and it has changed lots of things. there are few reasons 1. Your code is not null safe. 2) packages you are using are outdated. 3) Method and syntax in the packages has been changed.

Answer (score 0):

Your flutter project has been created some time ago, and Flutter has changed a lot since.

You have a variety of problems:

- Firstly your code is not null-safe. You can learn about null safety on the Dart documentation here: https://dart.dev/null-safety
- Some of the widgets you are using in your code don't exist anymore, `FlatButton` has been replaced with the new widget `TextButton`, you can learn more about the changes here: https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/buttons
- You seems to use a `TextTheme.title` to apply your theme to some widget, but the `.title` property has been removed, you can now use the `headline1` property instead
- You have some problems with dependencies, some dependencies can have new arguments or have removed some arguments over time. Update your code depending on their documentation